# Access object property in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this set

```
var data = [
    {"outlet_name":"Easy Lane Supermart","20130102_20130108":"0"},
    {"outlet_name":"Eunilaine Foodmart Kalayaan","20130102_20130108":"0"},
    {"outlet_name":"PUREGOLD PRICE CLUB, INC - VISAYAS","20130102_20130108":"0"}
];

$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    $.each(item, function (k,v) {
        $('#result').append(k,v);
    });
});
```

How can I make it only view all the values of `outlet_name` without using the item.outlet_name?

Comment: Please note that the problem has **nothing** to do with JSON at all. It seems you are confusing JavaScript object/array literals (constructs of the JavaScript language syntax) with JSON (a language-independent data-exchange format, like XML or CSV). I will edit your question accordingly. See also: [There is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 8):

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    console.log(item.outlet_name);
});
```

Or without jQuery:

```
for (var i=0;i<data.length;i+=1) {
    console.log(data[i].outlet_name);
}
```

Ok, if you want to iterate over each object you can write:

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) {
    console.log("Values in object " + i + ":");
    $.each(item, function(key, value) {
        console.log(key + " = " + value);
    });
});
```

Comment: i forgot, it should be, how can i view the values of outlet_name by not using item.outlet_name.

Comment: this is confusing im sorry, i mean how can i view the outlet_name or the second object, because the the key names are randomly generated.
like having [1] after the key name

Comment: It sounds like the data structure is confusing :-) If you have an object with unknown/random property names, you can't really access a specific property without knowing the name. It's not like an array where you can access a value by index ("pick the first value").

Answer (score 2):

This will provide exact answer...

```js
var data = [
    {"outlet_name":"Easy Lane Supermart","20130102_20130108":"0"},
    {"outlet_name":"Eunilaine Foodmart Kalayaan","20130102_20130108":"0"},
    {"outlet_name":"PUREGOLD PRICE CLUB, INC - VISAYAS","20130102_20130108":"0"}
];
for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
 for(var x in data[i]){
     console.log(x + " => " + data[i][x]);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is needing to do this from a JSON string for example

```
var myJson = [{"Code":"slide_1.png","Description":"slide_1"},{"Code":"slide_2.png","Description":"slide_2"},{"Code":"slide_3.png","Description":"slide_3"}]
```

You can use 
`var newJsonArray = JSON.Parse(myJson)` and you will get 
Array[3]
0
:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object

At which point you can access it by simply saying `newJsonArray[i].Code` or whatever property inside the array you want to use. Hope this helps!

Comment: `myJson` is not a string, and `JSON.Parse` will throw an error since it's `JSON.parse`.