# What would I code if I want to extract Alex's age from this array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var students = [ {
    name:"Mary",
    age: 10
  }, 
 
  {
    name:"Barbara",
    age:11
  }, 
 
  {
    name:"David",
    age:12
  },
  
   {
    name:"Alex",
    age:11
  } ];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access object property in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154224/access-object-property-in-array-of-objects)

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) syntax for iterating over the array elements. If the element has `.name` that you need, extract the `.age`:

```
function getAge(arr, name) {
    for (let s of students) {
        if (s.name == name) return s.age;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this function like this:

```
alert(getAge(students, 'Alex'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the item in the array whose `name` property is `"Alex"`, then get the item's `age` property:

```js
var students=[{name:"Mary",age:10},{name:"Barbara",age:11},{name:"David",age:12},{name:"Alex",age:11}];

let res = students.find(e => e.name == "Alex").age
console.log(res)
```